# ROS example program doesn't work with the Laptop webcam

Tags: ros, opencv, images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to work with the example program for [ROS - OpenCV integration](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages). When I run the program, there is no progress. I am not getting any response. I dont have any external or USB webcam. I have only the Laptop integrated webcam.

In the 'rosnodes list', this node is present. The tutorial doesn't offer any information about the output of the program.

My basic requirement: I need to get the image stream from the laptop webcam in ROS.

I tried  ' rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image '. A new window pops with no image data in it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218228/ros-example-program-doesn%27t-work-with-the-laptop-webcam/) by [karthik_puzzle](https://answers.ros.org/users/24044/karthik_puzzle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't sound like you running any ROS node to act as a driver for your webcam.

You need to find a driver node for your webcam, and run it in order to make the webcam topics (/camera/image and others) available for other nodes to use.

Most of the laptop webcams I've encountered are internal USB devices; I suspect yours is as well. You can confirm this by looking for webcams and/or unlabeled devices in the output from the `lsusb` command.

If you can confirm that your webcam is a USB device, try running one of the ROS driver nodes for USB webcams.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need a node witch publisch to the topic "/camera/image " your webcam pictures.

some ready to use  nodes are:

- http://wiki.ros.org/uvc_camera
- http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam
- http://wiki.ros.org/gscam

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-09-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2